# Does .NET contain methods to work with CSV files?

Tags: .net, csv

I intend to create a program working with CSV files (read and write).

I can easily make my own methods to work with that: collect values, read/write commas, load and save a file. But, is there a ready-to-use tool in .NET to avoid spending my time?

Comment: I've used this in past, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader works good

Comment: Yes. [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for creating CSV based String and use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  for creating an array out of CSV data.

Comment: This doesn't help much. It will appear to work at worst, then silently fail when your data contains commas or quotes.